# greatest common divisor proof

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-writing, gcd-and-lcm

> Suppose $\gcd(a,b)=1$. Does this necessarily imply that $\gcd(a,2b)=1$?

If $\gcd(a,b)=1$ then $\exists x,y \in \Bbb{Z} (ax+by =1)$

I don't see how to manipulate this equation to give me $ax+2by \neq 1$ I'm assuming that's what I have to do?

Comment: consider  $a=4$, $b=3$, then  $gcd(a,b)=1$, but  $gcd(a,2b)=gcd(4,6)=2 \neq 1$.

Comment: @Nizar Try LaTeX `\gcd` command → $\gcd$.

Comment: @CiaPan Thak you for the helpful note!

Answer (score 2):

Let $a=2$, $b=3$ then $\gcd(a,b)=1$ but $\gcd(a,2b)=\gcd(2,6)=2$, thus the implication is not true.

Answer (score 2):

No. If $a$ is even and $\textrm{gcd}(a,b)=1$ then $\textrm{gcd}(a,2b) = 2$.

Comment: Would you please state that this is true for all $a,b$, such that $\gcd(a,b)=1$. This will generalize your result .

Comment: This was assumed in the question. But I have added it to my answer.